# VBA - how to check if table in excel contains a value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet containing defined table named table123

I am pulling data from database and ( using loop ) going through all records.

What I want to do is ( thanks to VBA ) check whether values from database exist in the **table123**

What is the best solution to do this ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Say we want to know if there is **treasure** in *Sheet3*, table *Table1*

```
Sub TreasureHunt()
    Dim r As Range, IsItThere As Range

    Set r = Sheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table1").Range
    Set IsItThere = r.Find(What:="treasure", After:=r(1))

    If IsItThere Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "no treasure in the table"
    Else
        MsgBox "treasure is in the table"
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]